# How to Record any classes videos when i start recording it goes black screen

Tags: video, video-recording, screen-recording

when i start to recording classes video it goes black i am not able to record.

i tried today itself.Is any application available to record that session.i have tried many application but not able to record.i think something video restriction but how can i record .

Answer (score 0):

There are some programs worth trying. I personally enjoy using Snag-It by Techsmith for screen recordings. Pretty affordable, reliable, and comes with a trial period - so you can determine if it works for your use-case or not before investing.